# Git question: Branch or new repository for two similar copies of source code/project

Tags: git, branch, new-operator

I created a repository for a project. Now there is new project just with a few features changed. What I am going to do is creating a branch for the new project. I guess I have to switch back and forward between project 1 and project 2 by switching branches?

Another way is to create another repository for the new project with a copy of the same source code.

The latter sounds better to me. But want input from the Git gurus here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not a git guru but I would say that:

- If only some features are in the other project, you may need to apply fixes from the first project to the second or some features from one to the other.
- If you need to work on two branches simultaneously, you can definitely have two copies of the same remote repo locally.
- With git, you can locally handle many remotes that are not really related in one repo.

So, if I were you, I would go for one repo using clear branch names. But anyway, I don't think you'll face big issues by choosing one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

IF they are logically separate projects, I would put them in separate repos.

If they share code, I would extract the shared code to a common dependency.  That would also get its own repository, and I would use my build tools (not git) to manage the relationships among the resulting artifacts.